# Black screen for several seconds during startup

Tags: ios, robovm, javafxports

A colleague of mine tried to build the JavaFXPorts application of mine on his machine. The good thing is: after some minor updates to the `forceLinkClasses` part in the `build.gradle` file, it worked.
But...

While we can see one of the the white `Default*.png` images briefly, we are confronted with a black screen for about 5 seconds.

On the console, he could see the following output (amongst others):

```
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'ch.cnlab.disentis.resource.strings_en'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>ch.cnlab.disentis.resource.strings_en</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'ch.cnlab.disentis.resource.strings_de_CH'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>ch.cnlab.disentis.resource.strings_de_CH</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'ch.cnlab.disentis.resource.strings_de'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>ch.cnlab.disentis.resource.strings_de</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'ch.cnlab.disentis.resource.strings'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>ch.cnlab.disentis.resource.strings</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
Nov 4, 2016 11:32:44 AM com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7Support <clinit>
WARNING: Unable to load JDK7 types (annotations, java.nio.file.Path): no Java7 support added
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder$ClassLoaderFinderConcrete'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder$ClassLoaderFinderConcrete</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder$ClassLoaderFinderConcrete'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder$ClassLoaderFinderConcrete</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder$ClassLoaderFinderConcrete'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder$ClassLoaderFinderConcrete</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder$ClassLoaderFinderConcrete'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder$ClassLoaderFinderConcrete</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'com.sun.javafx.font.t2k.T2KFactory'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>com.sun.javafx.font.t2k.T2KFactory</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumMessagesBundle_de_CH'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumMessagesBundle_de_CH</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumMessagesBundle_de'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumMessagesBundle_de</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumMessagesBundle'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumMessagesBundle</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'com.oracle.jrockit.jfr.FlightRecorder'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>com.oracle.jrockit.jfr.FlightRecorder</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.resources.controls_de_CH'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.resources.controls_de_CH</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.resources.controls_de'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.resources.controls_de</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.resources.controls'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.resources.controls</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
setSwapInterval(1)
max rectangle texture cell size = 89
wrap rectangle texture = 2 x 2
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: AlphaTexture_Color.frag
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: FillRoundRect_Color.frag
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: DrawRoundRect_Color.frag
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: Texture_Color.frag
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: Solid_TextureRGB.frag
Loading Prism common native library ...
        succeeded.
setSwapInterval(0)
setSwapInterval(1)
setSwapInterval(0)
setSwapInterval(1)
setSwapInterval(0)
setSwapInterval(1)
setSwapInterval(0)
```

The delay seems to happen after the RoboVM warnings.

Does any one have any idea, what the cause for this might be?

Thanks and regards,
Daniel

PS: I needed to ask this, because he has no account on StackOverflow... So there might be some roundtrip time, if I need to ask him to test again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JoséPereda we found the issue: It was the iPhone used for the test. This is an older phone often used for developing. And obviously, it is in a "near-dead" state.

After we switched to another phone (iPhone 6S of another colleague :-D ) the application behaved like expected: being lightning fast during the test.

Answer (score 2):

Typically a black screen during a few seconds implies that there is some heavy load at startup.

Before going any further, make sure the load is strictly necessary, and check if doing it on a background task solves the issue.

If that doesn't help, there are several options to avoid the long black screen:

One, using a JavaFX *preloader*. Create your preloader class extending from `Preloader`, and provide a light weight scene (i.e. an image). In your build.gradle script add `preloaderClassName = 'full.preloader.class.name'`.

When the heavy load ends (this should be done in the `init` method), the application will be loaded, and you can hide the preloader stage.

You can read about preloaders [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/preloaders.htm) and [here](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2015/09/javafx-how-to-easily-implement-application-preloader-2/).

Using Gluon Mobile (Charm 4.0.1), use a light weight *Home View* that loads fast enough, and start loading on the background those heavy tasks. The user will have to use some navigation button or the Navigation Drawer to switch to the secondary view, but the black screen, if any, will be shorter.

And finally using a *Splash View* (already included in Charm 4+), it will allow showing an image or some label for a short while, while a task can be executed to load those heavy components. After that, the splash
can be dismissed, and the home view will be loaded.

Try any of these solutions and check if the problem goes away.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, José. The issue is, that except for some FXML loading, nothing is done at this point, so there should be no point for heavy load, whatsoever. On Android, you can barely see the native activity appearing. At the moment, I only use javafxport and a little of charm down, no view stuff, so unfortunately I cannot rely on that, for now. I thought I had some issues with the proposed preloader on iOS earlier, so I ditched it, but I will give it a try once again.

Comment: What's the iOS device? What happens with a very simple project?

Comment: Don't know. Since I don't have such devices, I need to ask my colleague to test it. I will ask him, if he can do that and will provide you with more details, OK?

Comment: It's an iPhone 5. And the issue with the preloader was probably, that I forget the forcelinkclasses entry... So i will let him try again and cross my fingers, that this solves it. Additionally I will also prepare a small application for testing as well, as you suggested.

Comment: The preloader speeds up the issue on Android. On iOS it's still the same. Additonally we can now see a log entry like this `QunatumRenderer:shutdown` - this happens before the main stage should be loaded. So it's even worse, since we stick with the black screen. A new application does not solve the issue: the single view mobile gluon application also takes several seconds on startup. My guess is, that the stage loading process takes far too long (regardless of the usage of FXMLs or not)

Comment: In general, with new iOS devices it's quite the opposite: startup time is faster than on Android ones. If the machine is slow, the preloader probably won't help since it is a stage as well.

Comment: What concerns me with the preloader is the `QunatumRenderer: shutdown` message. I tried to remove the CSS (for a test, only), if this would be an issue, but this seems not to be the case. I'm "kind-of" ok with the 2s delay on Android, but iOS seems out of the question for now. I simply don't understand, what the reason for the low `Stage#show()` performance could be...

Comment: Are you hiding the preloader's stage? That maybe related to that message. You can try not hiding it.

Comment: I did so, yes. I changed this as you supposed and now the UI is shown again. But it still takes more than 5s to appear, after the `Stage#show()` method was triggered. We also tried the JavaOne application - it also takes about 4s to load, before the main UI appears. Since I don't own a iPhone, I don't know, what the expected startup time is, but I don't believe, 4s. Maybe the iPhone has an issue (the colleague using it as a development phone)...

Comment: The JavaOne is quite complex app, so it could be reasonable that it takes more time than a simple project. It also uses a preloader, by the way. On my iPad Mini 4 the preloader is visible for less than 0.5 seconds, and the app total start time is two seconds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127544/discussion-between-dzim-and-jose-pereda).